# GSON throwing “Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING

Tags: json, gson

This is Json Object

```
[
   {
   "UserId":"demouser1",

   "Catagories":[
       {
       "CatagoryName":"Entertainment",
       "Persent":"25"
       },
       {
       "CatagoryName":"Household",
       "Persent":"25"
       },
       {
       "CatagoryName":"Movie",
       "Persent":"25"
       },
       {
       "CatagoryName":"Misc",
       "Persent":"25"
       }
   ],

   "RequestId":null,

   "ResponseStatus":false,

   "Token":null
   }

]
```

Used The Following approach to parse the above Json

```
public class CategoryEntity {

    private String CatagoryName;
    private String Persent;
    public String getCatagoryName() {
        return CatagoryName;
    }
    public void setCatagoryName(String catagoryName) {
        CatagoryName = catagoryName;
    }
    public String getPersent() {
        return Persent;
    }
    public void setPersent(String persent) {
        Persent = persent;
    }
}



import java.util.List;

public class Entity  {

    private String UserId;

    public String getUserId() {
        return UserId;
    }

    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        UserId = userId;
    }

    public List<CategoryEntity> getListCatagories() {
        return ListCatagories;
    }

    public void setListCatagories(List<CategoryEntity> listPMMCatagories) {
        ListCatagories = listPMMCatagories;
    }

    public String getRequestId() {
        return RequestId;
    }

    public void setRequestId(String requestId) {
        RequestId = requestId;
    }

    public boolean isResponseStatus() {
        return ResponseStatus;
    }

    public void setResponseStatus(boolean responseStatus) {
        ResponseStatus = responseStatus;
    }

    private List<CategoryEntity> ListCatagories;

    private String RequestId;

    private String Token;

    public String getToken() {
        return Token;
    }

    public void setToken(String token) {
        Token = token;
    }

    private boolean ResponseStatus; 

}
```

And 
Following approach to convert the json object to corresponding object

```
Gson gson =new Gson();

JsonPrimitive listCatagoriesElement= element.getAsJsonPrimitive();

                    System.out.println("listCatagoriesElement.getAsString()>>"+listCatagoriesElement.getAsString());

sysout prints:  listCatagoriesElement.getAsString()>>[{"UserId":"user1","ListCatagories":[{"CatagoryName":"Entertainment","Persent":"25"},{"CatagoryName":"Household","Persent":"25"},{"CatagoryName":"Movie","Persent":"25"},{"CatagoryName":"Misc","Persent":"25"}],"RequestId":null,"ResponseStatus":false,"Token":null}]

Entity entity = gson.fromJson(listCatagoriesElement, Entity.class);
```

Any ideas how should I fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: no. this is not a json object. read the doc : '[' indicates the begining of a json array.

Comment: @njzk2 According to [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com) it is valid.

Comment: @Dahaka : valid, yes, but still an array, not an object (was confused by the fantasy indentation)

Answer (score 2):

Your class `CategoryEntity` is correct, but in your class `Entity`, the attribute `ListCatagories` should be called `Catagories` to match the name in the JSON!

Apart from that, in order to parse the JSON you'd better do something like this:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Type listType = new TypeToken<List<Entity>>() {}.getType();
List<Entity> entities = gson.fromJson(yourJsonString, listType);
```

So you'll have a `List` containing just one `Entity` object, and you can access the values just with:

```
String catagoryNameI = entities.get(0).getCatagories().get(i).getCatagoryName();
String persentI = entities.get(0).getCatagories().get(i).getPersent();
```

You have to do this because your whole JSON response is an array, surrounded by `[ ... ]`, so you need to parse it into some `List`...

Comment: when i try this, i'm getting an exception which says 07-30 11:14:18.563: E/AndroidRuntime(299): Caused by: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING
07-30 11:14:18.563: E/AndroidRuntime(299):  at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:815)
07-30 11:14:18.563: E/AndroidRuntime(299):  at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:868)